# How to avoid loop in Ajax call

Tags: ajax

I have function `getData()` which make an ajax call and retrive `JSON` data. On success i call another function which is `marquee()` . inside marquee on finish event i call `getData()` again, But each time `getData()` when get called, it increases it's request to mentioned file `data.php`, For example on first call it call once, Second call it request twice, and then twice become 4times,8times and more and more, how to avoid this?!

```
function getData()
{
  $.get('data.php).done(function(response)
{
var data = JSON.parse(response);
if(data.Direction == "left")
{
$(".marquee").html("<span data-direction='"+data.Direction+"'>"+data.Message+"</span>");
}else if(data.Direction == "right"){ 
$(".marquee").html("<span data- direction='"+data.Direction+"'>"+data.Message+"</span>");
}    
});
}

function marquee()
{
   $(".marquee").marquee({duration : 10000}).bind("finished",function()
  {
    getData(); 
  });
}
```

I hope i was clear... Appreciate each answer.

Comment: Seems like an error in your logical structure. Try to think about what you want to achieve and how to achieve it. Then look at your conditions for when the events occure. You are running an infinite loop because the functions that call each other keeps being true in their condition. Having a function call a function that then again calls the previous function seems odd to me, but you might need. However, just check for what the conditions are and make sure you step out of the loop when you need to.

Comment: Hi, each time i should replace marquee script which make a marquee for text, i mean the retrived data, and each time this scrip need to be called to make marquee... I don't know how to make it possible. I got mixed up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you are calling marquee function, you are basically binding an event finished on to it. On multiple such function calls, you will have duplicate events. In your code setup, you need to unbind the function before binding it. Something like

```
$(".marquee").marquee({duration : 10000}).unbind("finished",getData).bind("finished",getData)
```

Ideally, you should bind only once so you do not have to unbind it again and again.